# Terminating from a while true loop (Calico IDE)

Tags: python, calico-project

I'm using the Graphics and Myro packages in the Calico IDE, can anyone figure a way for me to hit the 'q' key and have the program terminate? Currently when I hit the 'q' key I have to click the mouse on my window to terminate.

```
def main():
    win = Window(800,500)
    bg = Picture("http://www.libremap.org/data/boundary/united_states/contig_us_utm_zone_14_600px.png")
    bg.draw(win)
    while True:
        char = win.getKeyPressed()
        if char == 'q':
            win.close()
            break
        x, y = win.getMouse()
        MPO = Rectangle(Point(x,y), Point(x+10,y+10))
        MPO.fill = Color("white")
        MPO.draw(win)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Calico but suggest you try reorganizing like `def main(): ... win.run(main)` somewhat as at end of [pong.py example](http://svn.cs.brynmawr.edu/viewvc/Calico/trunk/examples/python/pong.py?pathrev=1443&view=diff&r1=1443&r2=533&diff_format=s)

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of Calico before, but from 5 seconds looking at [the docs](http://calicoproject.org/Calico_Graphics#Mouse), I see this:

> getMouse() - waits until user clicks and returns (x, y) of location in window

So, I'm willing to bet this is why you have to click on your window before hitting the Q key has any effect—because you're program is stuck waiting inside the `getMouse()` call, just as the docs say it should be.

Even if the docs didn't explain this, you could probably figure it out pretty quickly by adding some printing/logging and/or running in a debugger, to see where it's bogged down when it's not responding to your keypresses.

For example, the quick&dirty way to do this:

```
while True:
    print 'Before getKeyPressed'
    char = win.getKeyPressed()
    print 'After getKeyPressed, got', char
    if char == 'q':
        print 'About to close because of q'
        win.close()
        print 'Closed'
        break
    print 'Before getMouse'
    x, y = win.getMouse()
    print 'After getMouse, got', x, y
```

… and so on.

Of course in real life, you don't want to add a print statement for every single line of code. (And, when you *do* want that, you want a smarter way of instrumenting than manually writing all those lines.) But you can add a few to narrow it down to the general area, then zoom in and add a few more within that area, and so on, until you find the culprit.

Meanwhile, if you change your code to use `getMouseNow()` instead of `getMouse()`, that will solve the problem, but only by busy-looping and redrawing the window over and over as fast as possible, whether or not you've done anything.

What you really need here—as for any GUI app—is an event loop. I can see that there are functions called `onMouseDown` and `onKeyPress`, which looks like exactly what you need here.